# How to handle a "hidden" answer

Tags: support, answers, deletion, deleted-answers

I am confused by the message "This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted and converted to a comment" that I got when I tried to answer my own question.

After a year developing a better answer, I started to enter it as a new answer, but the software suggested I rework the hidden answer instead. I did that, but the confusing message was still there and I could not undelete. So I copied my answer as a new answer.

Soon a comment appeared under my new answer saying it was "identical to the deleted answer by the same user". Apparently the new "hidden" and "deleted" answer was somehow visible to others.

How do I straighten out the mess I have created? I want people to see my new answer on its own merits and not confuse it with the older, rejected answer?

The question is [A walk into the desert and back - have some hard-won answers but can't see the pattern](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733299/a-walk-into-the-desert-and-back-have-some-hard-won-answers-but-cant-see-the-p/4662989#4662989).

Comment: At the and for your post you write "The question is" and this is immediately followed by a link to *the deleted answer*. I'd guess you wanted to include a link *to the question* rather than a link to the answer? (Or maybe you wanted to write "The answer is" rather than "The question is"?)

Comment: Yes, I meant to include a link to the webpage with the question, the answer(s), and peoples' comments.

Comment: I saw the edited-deleted version of the answer, and was about to flag for moderator attention, to ask a moderator to undelete, when you posted the answer again as a new answer. So, I figured, well, that takes care of that. It might have worked out better, if you had mentioned in the new posting why you felt compelled to post it (come to think of it, I could have been more helpful by leaving a comment explaining the situation). By the way, users with enough points on the website are able to see deleted posts.

Answer (score 5):

Your answer was deleted by a moderator because, at the time, it appeared to be more of a comment than an answer.  Posts which are deleted by moderators cannot be *undeleted*, except by another moderator or SE staff.

In the future, it would be better to edit the deleted answer, and then flag it for a moderator, requesting that it be reopened.

What you did, posting a new answer, is also fine, but has the potential to be confusing to other users (who have already posted confused comments and have cast delete votes, likely as part of that confusion).  Do keep in mind that deleted questions are counted when the automatic question- and answer-ban systems do their jobs.

Comment: Is there any way to clean up after myself for the sake of future viewers?